# Customizing Y axis values in plot

Tags: r, plot, axis

I am trying to get my graph in R to change it's Y axis values.
Code:

```
plot(tree$NUM,tree$GRA,
     main="YSLOW Grades",
     xlab="HAR #",
     ylab="Grade",
     xaxt="n")
axis(1, at = seq(1, 20, by = 1), las=2)
```

I have figured out how to customize the x axis, but from all my researching I cannot find a way to simply change the Y axis too. Instead of having numbers, I want to customize the graph so that I can but letter grades in like A,B,C and so on. I assume it's a quick fix to do this but I really am clueless and the material seems lacking on the subject.

To clarify, I do not want to change Y axis label or the spacing, I simply want to be able to but letters on the Y axis, regardless of the data coming into it.

Comment: you need to know where you want to put the letters but `axis(2, at=1:4, labels=LETTERS[1:4])` should do the trick. (of course, suppress the axis drawing in your plot first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put `yaxt = "n"` and put the new y labels with `axis(2, ....)`. Example:

```
plot(1:20,1:20,
     main="YSLOW Grades",
     xlab="HAR #",
     ylab="Grade",
     xaxt="n", 
     yaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = seq(1, 20, by = 1), las=2)
axis(2, at = seq(1, 20, by = 1), label = rep(c("A", "B"), 10), las=2)
```

[image]